# LDAP group filter using SSSD

Tags: sssd

I am using RHEL 7.2 image and trying to provide group based LDAP authentication using SSSD. How do I enable group based filters using SSSD?

I am attaching my `sssd.conf` file and I haven't enabled TLS on LDAP server (OpenDJ). I changed the value of FORCELEGACY to yes on client machine to connect without TLS.

Below is my `sssd.conf` file

```
[domain/default]

 autofs_provider = ldap
 ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
 ldap_search_base = dc=mykronos,dc=internal
 id_provider = ldap
 auth_provider = ldap
 chpass_provider = ldap
 ldap_uri = ldap://[ldap-server-ip]:[port]
 ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
 cache_credentials = False
 ldap_tls_reqcert = allow
 ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts

[sssd]

 services = nss, pam, autofs
 config_file_version = 2
 domains = default

[nss]

 homedir_substring = /home

[pam]

[sudo]

[autofs]

[ssh]

[pac]

[ifp]

 ldap_access_filter = memberOf=cn=test,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

I am unable to restrict users from groups other than test from logging into the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = g1, g2
```

See `man sssd-simple` for more information.

By the way - SSSD does not allow authentication without either TLS or SSL.